# Why is my body on right after I moved my menu?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to make my own website based on WordPress and i found really nice theme (FANWOOD LIGHT BY DEVPRESS) but i need to move "Navigation" or Menu below the header. When i did it my body just moved to right and i dont know what happned.

There is the webpage on free webhosting: http://stbrezenecka.wz.cz/ (It's in Czech language)

There is my header.php:

```css
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package Fanwood Light
 * @since Fanwood Light 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
 <?php do_action( 'before' ); ?>
 <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
  <hgroup>
  <?php
   $header_image = get_header_image();
   if ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
     <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $header_image ); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" />
    </a>
   <?php } ?>
   <div class="header">
   <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
   <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
   </div>
  </hgroup>
 </header><!-- #masthead .site-header -->
 <div id="main-navigation">
  <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation-main" role="navigation">
   <h1 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'fanwood_light' ); ?></h1>
   <div class="assistive-text skip-link"><a href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'fanwood_light' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'fanwood_light' ); ?></a></div>

   <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
  </nav><!-- .site-navigation .main-navigation -->
 </div>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
<div id="main" class="site-main">
```

Threre is screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtAT8.png

Answer (score 0):

You have `<?php do_action( 'before' ); ?>` which creates a `<div>`, so after `</header>` add `</div>`

Comment: Hmmm...  can you post your sites url, or is it localhost?

Comment: It's localhost I didn't paid hosting yet. But i am going to upload it to free web.

Comment: The problem is probably related to the css then, which makes it very hard to trace without being able to view the site. You will have to use the console to check the css, as it sounds like a responsive theme, so something could be set to 'float'. I could speculate all day. Not sure if I can help more than that, sorry. Unless of course yo email the theme developers, tell them your story. They might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I did it! Only thing what I did I just removed navigation from **header.php** and moved in to **index.php** and it worked.